# Check a shop opening and closing times based on week days

Tags: php, datetime

I am stuck with an issue and that is I have to check whether current time lies between opening and closing time of a shop. below is my code that I am using

```
$order_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i a', $order_time);
$opening_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i a', $opening_time);
$closing_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i a', $closing_time);
if ($closing_time < $opening_time)
{
    $closing_time->add(new DateInterval('P1D')); //adding 1 day
}
if ( ($order_time >= $opening_time) && ($order_time <= $closing_time) ){
  return true;
}else{
    return false;
    }
```

the main issue is the shop remain open after 12am on weekends, means it will open at 10:am saturday and close at 01am and a customer come and place an order at 12am saturday but the above condition not work in this case. because opening time exceeds order time in that case.

any help regarding this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please show what your `$order_time` look alike and you had an extra `}` at the end

Comment: $order_time is the current date and time like Y-m-d H:i

Comment: So after removing extra `}` is it working or showing an error

Comment: copied that code from function that's why the extra } was there

Comment: it's still not working in weekend case